# Clustering based on pairwise similarity?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, cluster-analysis, similarity

Suppose I have a list of element pairs and corresponding similarity scores for each one. I want to be able to cluster the elements in this list based on their similarity to one-another. Is there an established method for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some density-based clustering algorithms such as [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) or [H-DBSCAN](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8215642). For example, if you want to find the neighbors of a pair `p` that they are located inside a circle with radius `epsilon` around `p`, you can compute all neighbors by their `1-sim(pi,p) < epsilon`. Because if `sim(pi,p)` is the similarity between `p` and `pi`, `1-sim(pi,p)` will be the distance of these two points.

Comment: This looks like a great solution! Thank you!

Comment: @chillsauce my pleasure.